# Login screen display not working

Tags: debian, gnome, kali-linux, login, xfce

I'm running a Kali Linux 2 system with Intel HD Graphics 5500. It originally came bundled with GNOME 3 however I quickly changed to XFCE due to preferences. However in about 2-3 weeks of usage I noticed that whenever I locked the computer and more specifically whenever the display turned itself off, when I went to turn the display back on the screen was completely red, then if I press any key it instantly turns blue and I can blindly log back into the computer. I have no idea what is going on here and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour of slock, one of the screen-lockers used by default by xflock4 which in turn is the screen-locker script used by Xfce power manager, if I'm not mistaken, and other apps/widgets part of Xfce.

When the computer is locked, it turns off the display and when you wake it, you need to type in your user password to unlock it. If you hit enter when waking or if you enter the wrong password, the screen turns red and when you start entering your password, it turns blueish.

xflock4 tries to use xscreensaver first and gnome-screensaver second as locker commands so if any of those suits you better, make sure you have them installed.